# how to set plot box aspect ratio

Tags: pgfplots

How can I set the box plot (i.e. axis) ratio of a usual 2D plot to a given value, say 4:3.

I don't want to use `unit vector ratio` since the quantities of the independent and dependent variables are of completely different orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If no `height` or `width` are specified, `pgfplots` uses the values of `axisdefaultheight` and `axisdefaultwidth`. If only one of these are specified (i.e., only `height=` or `width=`), the axes are scaled such that the aspect ratio of the default values is preserved. (See section 4.10.1 in the `pgfplots` manual)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\axisdefaultwidth{8cm}
\def\axisdefaultheight{6cm}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.style={scale only axis}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot{x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4cm]
\addplot{x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you should also add `scale only axis`, because now the "_box_" itself does not have a ratio of 4:3 ...

Comment: @StefanPinnow Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wished to achieve: setting the initial ratio by means of `axisdefaultwidth`, `axisdefaultheight`, and then being able to freely scale the plot by means of one of `width` or `height` while maintaining the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 9):

You mean (simply) setting the `width` and `height` of the axis while ignoring the labels?

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        % only scale the axis, not the axis including the ticks and labels
        scale only axis=true,
        % set `width' and `height' to the desired values
        width=0.4\textwidth,
        height=0.3\textwidth,
    ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: When you "predefined" it, you did it _after_ I have answered your question and you only did it (indirectly) in [your comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303213/how-to-set-plot-box-aspect-ratio/303273?noredirect=1#comment735120_303283) to erik's answer. So I don't know what your comment to my answer should be good for, sorry. As [egreg](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303213/how-to-set-plot-box-aspect-ratio/303273?noredirect=1#comment734931_303213) already stated in his comment below your question: You should know better how to ask a _good_ question ...

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Question: This is a `standalone` document, what is the `textwidth` of such a `tikzpicture`? According to what layout is the `textwidth` set?

Comment: @tush, I don't know the `\textwidth` of the `standalone` document class and it is not relevant for the answer. When you need a defined `width`, simply state that, e.g. `width=10cm`.

Comment: Either way, is it a good practice to use this setting when I later put this plot in my document? I.e. when specifying the plot width in `\begin{figure} \includestandalone[width=\textwidth]{path-to-file/filename}`?

Comment: @tush, that would make sense if you are sure that the `\textwidth` of `standalone` and your real document are the same. But if you later decide to change that ... I personally use the `external` library to avoid recompiling not changed plots over and over again. Have a look at the [PGFPlots manual section 5.6 (v1.17)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#section.5.6).

Comment: Thanks! I also just came across the [`tikzscale`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzscale) package, after studying this subject now. Looks like it was written just for that. Either way, thanks a lot for the help.