# Keeping aspect ratio of a plot whilst giving both width and height

Tags: pgfplots, pgfkeys

Ok, so after reading [how to set plot box aspect ratio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303213/how-to-set-plot-box-aspect-ratio) I can set the aspect ratio of my plots with a key, namely `aspect ratio` in a way that given the `width` or `height` it will scale to this value and also keep the predefined aspect ratio.

```
\pgfplotsset{aspect ratio/.code args={#1:#2}{%
  \def\axisdefaultwidth{#1 cm}%
  \def\axisdefaultheight{#2 cm}%
}
```

Now I was wondering if it was possible to have a key such as `keepaspectratio` from the `graphicx` package that even if given `height` **and** `width` the resulting plot would automatically ignore one of the dimensions in order to maintain the previously defined aspect ratio. Something like:

```
\pgfplotsset{keep aspect ratio/.code={%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\currentratio}{\currentwidth/\currentheight}%
  \ifnum\currentratio<\predefinedratio%
     ignore height%
  \else%
     ignore width%
  \fi%
}
```

Here's a dummy MWE for testing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{aspect ratio/.code args={#1:#2}{%
  \def\axisdefaultwidth{#1 cm}%
  \def\axisdefaultheight{#2 cm}},
  compat=newest
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[aspect ratio=16:9, width=.8\textwidth]
        \addplot[domain=0:10] {0.5*x+6};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[aspect ratio=4:3, width=.8\textwidth]
        \addplot[domain=0:10] {0.5*x+6};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[aspect ratio=4:3,
                 width=.8\textwidth,
                 height=.8\textheight,
                 %keep aspect ratio
                 ]
        \addplot[domain=0:10] {0.5*x+6};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It goes without saying that the third plot, after uncommenting `keep aspect ratio` should be the same as the second plot.

Comment: You would have to edit/replace the \pgfplots@set@default@size@options macro.  Frankly, it would be a whole lot easier to compute your own width and height values outside the axis environment using pgfmath.

Comment: Thank's @JohnKormylo for pointing the direction! I was looking in `pgfplots.code.tex` for some clues but without luck so far. About computing my own `width` and `height`, that seems like a good idea if always given both `height` *and* `width`. But how about when I give only one (`width` *or* `height`)?